# Unable to install TypeScript using NPM

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I'm not able to complete the Typescript installation using npm.

As the [documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript) suggest I run the following command:

```
npm install -g typescript
```

or

```
sudo npm install -g typescript
```

-

It seems ok until at about 20% of the process it can't proceed and this is the error that gets logged out in the shell.

```
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript/-/typescript-1.8.5.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with status code 504
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript/-/typescript-1.8.5.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: socket hang up
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript/-/typescript-1.8.5.tgz
npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "typescript"
npm ERR! node v5.4.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12

npm ERR! fetch failed with status code 504
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going to http://status.npmjs.org/#day all systems seem operational. Probably just a hickup. Try again

Comment: I can confirm it was just an hickup. Thank you anyway!